# How to update hidden field value when clicking on jQuery Accordion Header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a hidden field to store the active index for the accordion:

```
var activeIndex = parseInt($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidAccordionIndex').val());
$("#accordion").accordion({
    changestart: function () {
        var value = $(this).scrollTop();
        window.scrollTo(0, value);
    },
    autoHeight: false,
    event: "mousedown",
    active: activeIndex,
    collapsible: true,
    disabled: false,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        var index = $(this).children('h4').index(ui.newHeader);
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidAccordionIndex').val(index);
    }
});
```

Currently, the hidden field value is set in the codebehind. Therefore, if the user clicks on the accordion header, I would like to update the value of the hidden field according to the header that has been clicked.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't doing it already in your `change` handler ?

Comment: I tried to do it in the change handler but somehow it is not getting the new index. I thought I might have been using the wrong handler...

Comment: It is not getting the value of the header that has been clicked. Thus, it is not updating the hidden field value. Any clue?

Comment: Are you really using `<h4>` heading elements ? This works and code is the same as yours, except i use `<h3>`: [http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/4qhB6/](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/4qhB6/)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That was my problem. I had to change my tabs to h4... Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an exact same example as yours in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/4qhB6/) and it works like a charm.

The only possible reason for you to not find the index of the current header is that you might have `<h3>` headers in your markup and your selecting `<h4>` in your `change` handler.

Change one or the other and it should normally work.

Answer (score 1):

Use following function for `change` event handler:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
     var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
     $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidAccordionIndex').val(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this, is by adding a `class` called `accordionHeader` or something to each of the h3s. Then after the initial build of the accordian, call another event handler.

In my example I just performed a bind on `h3` for quickly providing a demo.

```
$("#accordion").accordion();

$('h3').bind('click', function() {
    $('#HiddenInputField').val($(this).children('a').html());
    alert($('#HiddenInputField').val());
});
```

[Simple working example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CczUV/9/)